# C# SQL Connection String problems

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, visual-studio, connection-string

I want to write a program using Visual Studio that allows the user to register and login using a SQL Server database. The problem is that the connection string that I get for my database doesn't seem to work. I've tried to modify it several times but it still doesn't work.

```
connection string = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename="C: \Users\H.Dani\Documents\glikDatabase.mdf";Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"
```

Do I need to use a SQL Server?

EDIT: here's a part of the code.

```
// ESTABLISH CONNECTION TO DATABASE
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename='C: \Users\H.Dani\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Glik\Glik\glikData.mdf';Integrated Security=True");

// TAKE FROM FIELDS AND ADD TO DATABASE
String conReg = "insert into users(username,password) values('"+ textBox1.Text +"','"+ textBox2.Text +"')";

con.Open();

SqlCommand regCmd = new SqlCommand(conReg, con);
regCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

MessageBox.Show("Successfully registered!");
con.Close();

textBox1.Clear();
textBox2.Clear();
textBox3.Clear();
glikRegister();
```

This error appears at `con.Open()`:

> Additional information: An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\Users\H.Dani\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Glik\Glik\glikData.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

Comment: Are you aware of the space after `C:` ?

Comment: How does it not work?

Comment: i think the quotations are at fault here and i've tried to remove them or replace them but it doesn't work as it gives me this error Additional information: An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\Users\H.Dani\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Glik\Glik\glikData.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is a space you have after `c:` and quote signs that need to be replaced.

Try the following connection string:

```
"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename='C:\Users\H.Dani\Documents\glikDatabase.mdf';Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"
```

Comment: yea, I've just tried to modify it again by removing the quotes and space but it didn't work and i received this error: "Additional information: An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\Users\H.Dani\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Glik\Glik\glikData.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share." so I used the single quotes as well but it still gave me the same error from before.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 connection string = @"Data Source= (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\H.Dani\Documents\glikDatabase.md;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"
```

Comment: just tried that but it gives me an error: Additional information: An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\Users\H.Dani\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Glik\Glik\glikData.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

Comment: try to refresh or connect database again and replace it with new connection string